# Is there a way to count number of children in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    mImageLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mProcessLike = true;
            //mLikeCount.setText("numLikes");
            mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    if(mProcessLike)
                    {
                        if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()))
                        {
                            mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                            numLike--;
                            mProcessLike = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("Liked");
                            mProcessLike = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });

            mDatabaseLike.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                {
                    numLike = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child("numLike").setValue(numLike);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I was struggling with increasing count when like button is pressed and store that count number into the database "Like". I have declared DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike and it looks like this. [image: mDatabaseLike]

I am trying to count the number of children in each like(the ones with "Liked" string) and store them into each key(ex. Kb6cSLImN_7lrPyAr2Q) as numLike. When I click like button, it updates the count, but when I click the button again to remove that like, the number doesn't decrease.

Please help!. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the ChildEventListener from the onClickListener so you're always keeping track of the Likes. You're also never decreasing the like count, you're just changing it locally. You have to set the value once you decrease it like this: `mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child('numLike').setValue(numLike);`

I'd also recommend not keeping track of likes like that, and use [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) instead. It will deal with conditions where two users click Like at the same time. With your current implementation, if two users click it at the same time, one like would overwrite the other and only increase by one rather than by two.